# Почему может не выполняться задача?

Tags: python

Видимых ошибок нет,но и ответ не выдаётся,эксперты,какие могут быть варианты?
Задача:Алгоритм вычисления значения функции F(n), где n – натуральное число,
задан следующими соотношениями:
F(n) = 3×n - 3 при n <= 2;
F(n) = F(n - 2) + 2×F(n – 1) + 7, если n > 2.
Чему равно значение функция F(20)?

```
def F(n):
    if n <= 2:
        return F(n) == (3*n)-3
    elif n > 2:
        return F(n) == F(n-2)+2*F(n-1)+7

print(F(20))
```

Comment: `Видимых ошибок нет` нууу, бесконечная рекурсия вполне себе ошибка (PS хотя нет, она не бесконечна, извините)

Comment: ....как решить? хотя нет,не надо

Comment: сам попробую понять)

Comment: Что значит «нет результата»? Подождать надо и ты увидишь ошибку о том, что достиг максимальную глубину рекурсии.

Answer (score 2):

Уберите `F(n) ==`  из двух строк.

Ну нельзя же  так буквально записывать задание в коде.

И `elif` замените на `else` или вообще удалите, это не вредно, но бесполезно.

Comment: @Арменка Вопрос решён?

Answer (score 1):

Ваша функция возвращает не `int`, а `bool`. Перепишите программу так:

```
def F(n):
    if n <= 2:
        return 3*n-3
    return F(n-2)+2*F(n-1)+7

print(F(20))
```

Вывод:

> 52667940

Comment: @0xdb, благодарю за правку